# How to update without the last part of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider this string:

`http://kliks.affiliate4you.nl/?adv=17847&web=1426&subid=4083&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bartsmit.com%2Fshop%2Fnl%2Fbsnl%2Fpaw-patrol%2Fpaw-patrol-racers-pup-zuma**%3Fchannel_code%3D83%26product_code%3D94193039%26referer%3Da4you&linkinfo=czA4YBartSmit**`

- I have thousand of strings like this in a database field.
- I want to delete the bold part of the string.
- I know that it starts with `%3Fchannel_code`
- I know it ends with `czA4YBartSmit`
- Between those two it is different in each record

I want to do something like: update table set string = (string, but without the part starting with `%3Fchannel_code` and ending with `czA4YBartSmit`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `replace`, `substring`, `charindex` this works for even when the removed string is not at the end or start:

```
update table 
set string = 
replace(string ,
substring(
string ,charindex('%3Fchannel_code',string ),charindex('czA4YBartSmit',string ))
       ,'')
```

*sqmple:*

```
declare @str varchar(500)='http://kliks.affiliate4you.nl/?adv=17847&web=1426&subid=4083&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bartsmit.com%2Fshop%2Fnl%2Fbsnl%2Fpaw-patrol%2Fpaw-patrol-racers-pup-zuma%3Fchannel_code%3D83%26product_code%3D94193039%26referer%3Da4you&linkinfo=czA4YBartSmit'
select replace(@str,
               substring(@str,charindex('%3Fchannel_code',@str),charindex('czA4YBartSmit',@str))
               ,'')
```

*Output:*

```
http://kliks.affiliate4you.nl/?adv=17847&web=1426&subid=4083&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bartsmit.com%2Fshop%2Fnl%2Fbsnl%2Fpaw-patrol%2Fpaw-patrol-racers-pup-zuma
```

Comment: Works great. The @str is to be replaced by database-fieldname, and the declare is not used then. I also added charindex('3Fchannel_code', kado_url) > 0 to my where-clause to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be able to update the rows in the table using a combination of [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to locate the start position, and `LEFT` to truncate the string.

You can use '3Fchannel_code' and 'czA4YBartSmit' as a filter criterion to limit the update to just strings which contains, and ends in these terms respectively. Also, `%` is used as a wildcard when used with `LIKE`, so needs to be escaped with `[%]`.

```
BEGIN TRAN;

UPDATE MyTable
SET [string] = 
LEFT([string], charindex('%3Fchannel_code', [string]) - 1)
FROM MyTable
WHERE [string] like '%[%]3Fchannel_code%czA4YBartSmit'
-- Check the update with a SELECT

-- If you are Happy, COMMIT, otherwise ROLLBACK
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/257b3/1)

There's a good overview of doing string manipulation with `LEFT, RIGHT and CHARINDEX` on [MSDN here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx)

Caveat: Before updating data in this way, recommend that you wrap the update in a transaction, just in case.

Comment: Works great. Eventually used LEFT(kado_url, charindex('3Fchannel_code', kado_url) - 2) to avoid problems with the %. I also added charindex('3Fchannel_code', kado_url) > 0 to my where-clause to be sure.